# cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer

Tags: opencv, python-3.6, face-recognition

I am creating a face recognition system using Python and idle on these versions:Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit),Anaconda 4.4,idle

When I try to train the face recognizer I am getting an error like:

AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer'

Here i have attached the code

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Path for face image database
path = 'dataset'
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer()


def getImagesWithID(path):
     imagePaths=[os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
     faceSamples=[]
     Ids=[]
     for imagePath in imagePaths:
         faceImg=Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')
         faceNp=np.array(faceImg,'unit8')
         ID=int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])
         faces.append(faceNP)
         IDs.append(ID)
         cv2.imshow("training",faceNp)
         cv2.waitKey(10)
     return np.array(IDs), faces

Ids,faces=getImagesWithID(path)
recognizer.train(faces,Ids)
recognizer.save('recognizer/trainningData.yml')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: There is no need for the code after the `recognizer` line.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  The editor/IDE you use is also not a factor.  Look in the cv2.face doc and see what attributes are available.

Comment: What OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: @eshirima we are using opencv 2.4.13 version

Comment: You have to use a newer version of opencv, you can easily install opencv3.4.0 using `conda install -c conda-forge opencv `

Answer (score 0):

That is such an old version of OpenCV that they didn't even have Python docs for it.

Now going off of their [C++ documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.6/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html?highlight=createlbphfacerecognizer#createlbphfacerecognizer), I would say the Python equivalent was `cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`. It was not yet moved to `face` by then.

I would highly recommend you update to at least OpenCV 3.X or else you'll keep running into these issues.